# ListView in child view is not refreshed correctly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

There is a ListView. I make a transaction in Cloud Firestore by changing the field of an element when I click on it in the list. Data in the database changes as it should, but after this action all the elements in the list disappear (although there is .onAppear {fetchData}). An important point: this is a child view, there is no such problem in the parent view.

I also added a button at the bottom of the list to execute fetchData (), when I click on it, the data returns to the list

What could be the problem? Thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = BooksViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(viewModel.books) { book in
               VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Button("Update data"){
                    let updBook = book
                    self.viewModel.myTransaction(book: updBook)
                }
                 Text(book.title)
                   .font(.headline)
                 Text(book.author)
                   .font(.subheadline)
                 Text("\(book.numberOfPages) pages")
                   .font(.subheadline)
               }
             }
             .navigationBarTitle("Books")
             .onAppear() {
               self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
            Button("update list"){
                self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class BooksViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var books = [Book]()

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }

            self.books = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Book? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Book.self)
            }
        }
    }

    func deleteBook(book: Book){
        if let bookID = book.id{
            db.collection("books").document(bookID).delete()
        }
    }

    func updateBook(book: Book) {
        if let bookID = book.id{
            do {
                try db.collection("books").document(bookID).setData(from: book) }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func addBook(book: Book) {
        do {
            let _ = try db.collection("books").addDocument(from: book)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func myTransaction(book: Book){
        let bookID = book.id

        let targetReference = db.collection("books").document(bookID!)

        db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
            let targetDocument: DocumentSnapshot
            do {
                try targetDocument = transaction.getDocument(targetReference)
            } catch let fetchError as NSError {
                errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
                return nil
            }

            guard let oldValue = targetDocument.data()?["pages"] as? Int else {
                let error = NSError(
                    domain: "AppErrorDomain",
                    code: -1,
                    userInfo: [
                        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve population from snapshot \(targetDocument)"
                    ]
                )
                errorPointer?.pointee = error
                return nil
            }

            // Note: this could be done without a transaction
            //       by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
            transaction.updateData(["pages": oldValue + 1], forDocument: targetReference)
            return nil
        }) { (object, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Transaction failed: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Transaction successfully committed!")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Parent view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
     @ObservedObject var viewModel = BooksViewModel() 

     var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List(viewModel.books) { book in 
               VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Button("Update"){
                    let delBook = book
                    self.viewModel.myTransaction(book: delBook)
                }
                 Text(book.title)
                   .font(.headline)
                 Text(book.author)
                   .font(.subheadline)
                 Text("\(book.numberOfPages) pages")
                   .font(.subheadline)
               }
             }
             .navigationBarTitle("Books")
             .onAppear() { 
               self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()){
                Text("Second View")
            }
        }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your `BooksViewModel`?

Comment: @pawello2222 Yes of course. I updated the question

Comment: Did you try using a `List { ForEach(viewModel.books, id: \.self) { book in ...` instead of `List(viewModel.books)`?

Comment: @pawello2222 There is an error: "Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Book' conform to 'Hashable' ". But if I delete the second argument (id:) the error disappears and the problem remains

Comment: You have to use the `id` parameter for a dynamic list. Try conforming your `Book` to `Hashable` if you can (`struct Book: Hashable { ...`).

Comment: @pawello2222 Ok, I conformed Book to Hashable by adding some variable (var hashValue: Int { return title.hashValue }) but the problem remains

Comment: @pawello2222 For some reason, parent view works without adding ForEach

Comment: Then it might be a problem with how your views (and its view models) interact with each other.

Comment: @pawello2222 added parent view code, maybe this will help

Comment: @pawello2222 wow, I deleted all the code in the parent view except NavigationView and NavigationLink and it works as it should... but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution might be that your Views and its ViewModels interfere with each other. It looks like you create two instances of the same `BookViewModel`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
     @ObservedObject var viewModel = BooksViewModel() 

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = BooksViewModel()
```

Try creating one `BooksViewModel` and pass it between views (you can use an `@EnvironmentObject`).